# How do i get a selected item in the IEnumerable<SelectListItem>?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity

This is my ViewModel:

```
//Categoria da Materia
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListaCategorias { get; set; }

  //Categoria Matéria que foi selecionada pelo usuário na área pública
    public string CategoriaMateriaSelecionada { get; set; }
```

This is My Controller:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCategoria()
        {
            var query = contexto.CategoriaMateria.OrderBy(x => x.Nome).ToList();

            var categorias = query.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                Text = x.Nome
            }).ToList();

            return categorias;
         }
```

And This is My view:

```
<label class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoriaMateriaSelecionada)
        </label>
        <label class="editor-field">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoriaMateriaSelecionada, Model.ListaCategorias)
        </label>
```

My problem is when i'am trying to save My CategoriaMateriaSelecionada like in this code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Novo(NovoViewModel novoViewModel , string imagemCapa)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Materia noticia = new Materia()
                                      {
                                          CategoriaMateria = contexto.CategoriaMateria.Find(Convert.ToInt64((novoViewModel.CategoriaMateriaSelecionada))),
                                          Titulo = novoViewModel.Titulo,
                                          Chamada = novoViewModel.Chamada,
                                          Corpo = novoViewModel.Corpo,
                                          DataPublicaco = DateTime.Now,
                                          Status = novoViewModel.Status,
                                          Imagem = contexto.Imagem.Find(Convert.ToInt64(imagemCapa))
                                      };

                contexto.Materia.Add(noticia);
                contexto.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }

            return View(novoViewModel);
        }
```

The program show me an error:
The ViewData item that has the key 'CategoriaMateriaSelecionada' is of type 'System.String' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.
in the moment i'am enter in the HTTpPOST the listaCategoria is null why?
What is the problem why this cant work?

Comment: I don't see that you initiate your ListaCategorias.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like so....

this example for demonstration only

```
//Categoria da Materia
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ListaCategorias 
{ 
    get { return GetCategoria(); }   
}
```